# Reported critical issues with version 17.0.0. google play warning

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-services, warnings, safetynet

I got this warning when I was publishing my app

The developer of play-services-safetynet (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet) has reported critical issues with version 17.0.0. Consider upgrading before publishing a new release.

Here's what the SDK developer told us:
The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

How do I remove the critical issue and get my app into production?

Comment: I got this warning too, although I don't use safety net anywhere in my code. It's actually the first time I hear that it exists.

Comment: It seems that Firebase-Auth is using this `com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet`

Comment: I am getting the same warning, but I actually do not have `safetynet` anywhere in my code. I am using Firebase-Auth, so it may be coming from there. Is there a way to solve this without just excluding it?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, My app got crashed after installing. I used firebase-auth not safetyNet. Any work around for this for react-native ?

Comment: I also got this warning for my flutter app. But will the app be released with this warning?
Review is taking really long time.

Comment: We use only recaptcha from safetynet, but still recently got this message, the version 18.0.1. The problem is new integrity api has no captcha as I see in the docs. So, are they going to add it there soon and when we need to migrate or they will remove this warning?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3890) in FIrebase GitHub. Flutterfire plugins [can do nothing](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9085) until it is fixed on the native level.

Answer (score 19):

SafetyNet is a set of APIs from Google Play Services for developers to ensure that apps are running in a safe environment. It is **optional** for app developers, and app developers can choose to use it or not. [SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation) prevents an app from working if an app’s developer doesn’t want it to work on devices which are rooted, tampered, running custom ROM, or infected with malware.

**Banking apps, Snapchat and Netflix** are examples that uses something called SafetyNet to detect whether your device is rooted or not, and blocks access to those features.

**For those apps which are using SafetyNet:**

In June 2022, Google announced that we should start integrating with the [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview) as soon as possible. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more. SafetyNet Attestation will continue to work for your app as of now.

At the end of June 2023, developers that have migrated to the new API will be able to continue using the old SafetyNet Attestation on older versions of their apps, but those that have not migrated will not be able to do so.

At the end of June 2024, Google says SafetyNet Attestation will be retired entirely.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, My app got crashed after installing. I used firebase-auth not safetyNet. Any work around for this for react-native ?

Comment: This won't be a reason of crash in your app as you are not using safetyNet. So, it is showing you just a warning because of firebase using some code related to it. Better to use crashAnalytics to debug the actual reason of crash.

Comment: Ok. I created .aab file for play store then I download app from bundle explorer. This APK is got crashed. but I also have release build  APK with no changes and it's working fine. Don't know .aab file converted by play store not working.

Answer (score 14):

If you are not using safety net anywhere just do the below changes in your code.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth') {
        exclude module: "play-services-safetynet"
    }
```

Comment: So the problem is related only to firebase-auth?,or  is there another dependency that is using safetynet?

Comment: I found it only in firebase auth till now

Comment: Why would the exclusion of the module be the solution here? Surely we should be getting an updated firebase auth sdk from google since it is their products using their products?

Comment: @PietervanderVyver I Hope, it would be solved in the updated firebase auth SDK but till now I only got this solution.

Comment: Has anyone found if this causes any problems by excluding play-services-safetynet?

Comment: when i added this.. its not sending OTP to mobile number. show error toast. so removed it now its working.. will not work for phone number auth in my case.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, My app got crashed after installing. I used firebase-auth not safetyNet. Any work around for this for react-native ?

Comment: Will the app be published even though this warning?

Comment: @kragekjaer you can publish your app on the play store with this warning but google sent you a critical warning message in you play console inbox for same warning

Comment: This didn't removed the warning on play-console @sukhbeer, do you have suggestions to move out of the warning, or how would be able to migrate.
Even the app is not rejected, but taking more the 4+ days, don't know why.

Comment: @neon97 I've just exclude module: "play-services-safetynet" from firebase-auth and it work I think you need to test your dependencies tree it might be possible that apart from auth library other dependencies use it internally

Comment: Does Firebase Auth still work properly when you exclude this? Does 2FA work properly? This doesn't seem to be the best solution, Firebase is a part of Google and if Google discontinues SafetyNet, Firebase should remove this from their code.

Comment: Indeed, the application takes a very long time to be moderated, they probably put it to the test in much more detail, I'm still waiting... The exception listed here as a solution worked for me when I published my other application everything went without a warning in PlayConsole, but I don't use firebase-auth

Comment: Please do not exclude the safety net module from the auth library, it might break the code. Ignore the warning for now. This warning is nothing but a miscommunication between firebase and the google team. Firebase auth uses safety net attestation API internally(which is deprecated) and THEY need to perform the migration and not us. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3890

Comment: Don't use this solution if you are using firebase authentication with flutter, it will break your app! Just like others have said in this thread, you can ignore the warning for now and publish your app.