# how fix com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet error

Tags: flutter, dart

com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0

The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

Google play store error how fix this for flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reported critical issues with version 17.0.0. google play warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904471/reported-critical-issues-with-version-17-0-0-google-play-warning)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's just a warning, it still works to release the app.

Comment: Inaccurate. The app stays in review.

Comment: What do you get in the review feedback @DoingThingsOccasionally?