# How to fix Remove the play-services-safetynet warning?

Tags: flutter, safetynet, safetynet-api

I am attempting to place my app in production but, continuously get the "warning"/error that wont allow me to deploy my app to production.

> Critical issues have been reported with the following SDK versions:
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.0
>
> What the SDK developer told us: The SafetyNet Attestation API is being
> discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin
> migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play
> Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet
> Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better
> error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at
> https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

I have attempted the fix in [Stack Fix1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028990/play-store-warning-play-services-safetynet-com-google-android-gmsplay-servic) and in [Stackfix2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904471/reported-critical-issues-with-version-17-0-0-google-play-warning) but no luck.

I am using

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.4
  json_annotation: ^4.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
  image_cropper: ^1.0.1
  path: any
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  clippy_flutter: ^1.1.0
  rxdart: ^0.26.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  bubble_bottom_bar: ^1.2.0
  flutter_rating: ^0.0.2
  sticky_headers: ^0.1.7
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.10
  geolocator: ^7.6.2
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.19
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  source_gen: ^1.0.0
  flutter_counter: ^1.0.3
  share: ^0.6.4
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  dropdown_menu: ^1.1.1
  flutter_flip_view: ^1.0.3
  permission_handler: ^8.1.6
  giffy_dialog: ^1.7.0
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  js: ^0.6.0
  universal_html: ^1.2.3
  square_in_app_payments: ^1.7.4
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  provider: 
  blinkid_flutter:
  flutter_mapbox_autocomplete:
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0 
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.1
  edge_alert: ^0.0.1
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0 
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.4
  badges: ^2.0.2
  platform: ^3.1.0
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0


  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.3.1





  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  emojis: ^0.9.3
  firebase_app_check: ^0.0.6+18
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^5.0.2
```

and my build.gradle dependencies are:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'   
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth') {
        exclude module: "play-services-safetynet"
    }
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.0.1'

}
```

And I'm using     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

Firebase integration:
I [image]

But every time I send publish the app, it hangs "In Review" and nothing happens. It has been 2 weeks now and I'm not sure how to remove the Play Services Safety Net error/warning.

Any Ideas on how to remove the safetynet error? I'm pretty sure the issue is with firebase, that is why I added the ignore dependency but. No luck

Comment: Run `gradle app:dependencies` and check what library still using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0` and try update this library

Comment: I get this error instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028990/play-store-warning-play-services-safetynet-com-google-android-gmsplay-servic?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: same issue, Have you found any solution. App is in review for 4 days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please exclude `play-service-safetynet` in file `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  //....
}
//add below script  
configurations.all { 
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}
```

refer Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712387/how-to-solve-critical-issues-have-been-reported-with-the-following-sdk-versions)!

Comment: Beware. You need to confirm that all 3rd party libraries will not use Safenet in runtime. Just release my app with this line and boom, crashes when users use the feature provided by one of my 3rd party libraries.

"The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNet;"