# How to solve Critical issues have been reported with the following SDK versions: com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0

Tags: android, react-native

I got this warning when I was publishing my app

> The developer of play-services-safetynet
> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet) has reported critical
> issues with version 17.0.0. Consider upgrading before publishing a new
> release.

Here's what the SDK developer told us:

> The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by
> the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to
> avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the
> integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like
> Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start
> migrating at
> https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

How To Solve :

```
exclude play-service-safetynet in file android/app/build.gradle :
```

```
dependencies {
  //....
}
configurations.all { 
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}
```

Comment: put your app level build.gradle file otherwise we cant help you

Comment: is it enough for solution??